# inserting values from PHP in a div with a specific ID

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

edit: i found a solution using jquery and append()
from php, i build the array that contains all the information i want to insert into the tab divs. Then i send this array to jquery by encoding the  array into json end echoing it,  and catching the array using getJSON. Now i can successfully add my data into the respective divs. Thanks for the help

Here is my situation: on my main page, a user can input a link and send it to the database alongside the link's type (if it's a link about nature, news, technology, entertainment..)
Now on the same page, i have a div that is loaded up without refreshing the entire page, and inside this div i have a tabbed interface where each tab represents a link's type. Inside each tab resides a link of the respective type.
In my database, i store the link and the link's type

Here is my problem: how can i correctly fill the tabs with the links, knowing that the ID of a tab to fill is only known when reading the database in the PHP script

Here is the div with the tab interface

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab_nav">  
        <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#Technology">Technology</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#Sport">Sport</a></li>  
    </ul>  
    <div id="News">
    </div>
    <div id="Technology">
    </div>
    <div id="Sport">
    </div>
</div>
```

What i want to do is insert a link of a certain type into the div with the corresponding ID. The link's type (and the div's ID) is only known when fetching the database.

I'm new to making websites, and i am completely stuck here. I don't know how to deal with this.

Thank you!

Comment: There are a number of ways to approach this.  What have you tried?

Comment: Haven't tried anything but i had an idea, right now in the php script, i can put all the links and the types from the database into an array. i'm using the PDO way to get my data from the tables. My idea was to pass the array to javascript or jquery, then jquery would put correctly into the div the desired data

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
   t = $(this).text();
   $("#" + t).text($(this).attr("href"))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$('a').each(function(){
   $(this).clone().appendTo("#" + $(this).text());
})​
```

Here is the whole code: [Click here!](http://jsfiddle.net/KePyM/1/)

**Note:** It uses jquery. Just want to say that since you said your new to the web thingy.